# MySQL insert from multiple rows from multiple tables

Tags: mysql

I have MySQL Tables

**ColorOptions**

```
+-----------+---------+------+--------+
| productId | colorId | cost | sorter |
+-----------+---------+------+--------+
|         1 |       1 |   10 |      1 |
|         1 |       3 |    0 |      2 |
|         1 |      33 |  .04 |      5 |
|         2 |       3 |   10 |      1 |
|         2 |       4 |    0 |      2 |
+-----------+---------+------+--------+
```

**Product2Category**

```
+-----------+------------+
| productId | categoryId |
+-----------+------------+
|         1 |          1 |
|         1 |          3 |
|         2 |          1 |
|         3 |          1 |
|         4 |          2 |
+-----------+------------+
```

My goal is to copy all the colorOptions for a specific product and apply them to all of the other products in that category (replacing existing options). So productId 2 & 3 (but not 4) will have all the same rows in the ColorOptions table as productId 1. Something like

```
DELETE FROM `ColorOptions` WHERE `productId` IN (SELECT `productId` FROM `Product2Category WHERE `categoryId` = 1 AND `productId` != 1)
```

This remove current entries so they can be updated with:

```
INSERT INTO `ColorOptions` (`productId`,`colorId`,`cost`,`sorter`)
SELECT (SELECT `productId` FROM `Product2Category WHERE `categoryId` = 1 AND `productId` != 1) as 'product',`colorId`,`cost`,`sorter` FROM `ColorOptions` WHERE `productId` = 1
```

I know that does work because of the subquery, but that is the best way I can explain what I am looking for. I am have been trying a bunch of JOINs, but no luck.

Here is desired result:

```
+-----------+---------+------+--------+
| productId | colorId | cost | sorter |
+-----------+---------+------+--------+
|         1 |       1 |   10 |      1 |
|         1 |       3 |    0 |      2 |
|         1 |      33 |  .04 |      5 |
|         2 |       1 |   10 |      1 |
|         2 |       3 |    0 |      2 |
|         2 |      33 |  .04 |      5 |
|         3 |       1 |   10 |      1 |
|         3 |       3 |    0 |      2 |
|         3 |      33 |  .04 |      5 |
+-----------+---------+------+--------+
```

Comment: Your query does not reveal what you are trying to do here (at least not to me).  Please show us your expected output.

Comment: Both `productId = 1` and `productId = 2` correspond to `categoryId = 1`. So which color options are set for category 1?

Comment: Updated the question to clarify.

Comment: As clarification goes, this is somewhat disappointing. Why does the example begin with DELETE?

Comment: Updated to show the desired result and to clarify the delete.